# Turn off Internet Connection Sharing in Windows 10

Tags: networking, windows-10

I recently enabled internet connection sharing on my Ethernet connection and I'm now trying to disable it.

The tab that I enabled it in ("Sharing") looks like it has disappeared, which is odd, so I don't know where to go to disable this.

[image: Missing Sharing Tab]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tab will only show up if there are some other *enabled* network device(s):

[image]

[image]

Which *sort of* makes sense since if there are none, no *other network users* will be sharing the connection anyway.

So the solution is probably connecting and/or enabling another network device. Otherwise you might need to fiddle with the registry.

Comment: Ugh. Okay, this makes sense. Also solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. To be honest I found that sucks too. Hope that one day Microsoft will polish it.